# Graphing lat/long data points on US map 50 states including Alaska & Hawaii

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a bubble plot similar to this bubble plot from plot.ly with all 50 US states, with Alaska and Hawaii relocated.

[image]

The data set would have 5 variables, zip code, latitude longitude (merged on from the zipcode package), amount and score. The amount and score variables would be represented by the size and color of the bubble.

I've been trying to do this using ggplot. The first method uses the maps package. However, I don't know how I would move the Alaska and Hawaii and refit it, as well as draw the border of the US.

**This is what I get.**

[image]

```
US <- map_data("world") %>% filter(region=="USA")


p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = US, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill="grey", alpha=0.3) +
  geom_point(data = df, alpha = 0.5, aes(x=df$lon, y=df$lat, size=df$manual_prm, color=df$wcng_score)) +
  scale_size_continuous(name="Premium", trans="log",  range=c(0.1,4)) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0.1, 0.9)) +
  scale_color_viridis(name = "Scores", trans="log", option="magma") +
  theme_void() + 
  coord_map() +
  ggtitle("Scores") +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0.85, 0.8),
    text = element_text(color = "#22211d"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA), 
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA), 
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA),
    plot.title = element_text(size= 16, hjust=0.1, color = "#4e4d47", margin = margin(b = -0.1, t = 0.4, l = 2, unit = "cm"))
  )
```

The other method involves using albersusa package. However, I get almost the same issue. This version also made the boundaries invisible.

**Here is the result.**
[image]

I left out the scales.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(albersusa)
library(broom)


USA <- usa_composite(proj="laea")  # creates map projection 
USA_MAP <- tidy(USA, region="name")

q <- ggplot() + 
  geom_map(data = USA_MAP, map = USA_MAP, aes(map_id = id), fill=NA, size = 0.1)+
  geom_point(data = df, alpha = 0.5, aes(x=df$lon, y=df$lat, size=df$manual_prm, color=df$wcng_score)) +
  theme_void() +
  coord_map()
```

How can I get something similar to what plotly produces?

Answer (score 1):

I'll follow up on neilfws suggestion to use fiftystater. Unfortunately I don't have your df object so cannot recommend how best to match size, alpha and colours. However, the plot.ly map looks to be in USA Albers equal-area projection so I have also provided code to get the projection looking better. This requires transforming the coordinates with sf and using coord_sf instead of coord_map in ggplot.

```
library(fiftystater)
library(sf)

epsg <- 102003
US <- st_as_sf(fifty_states, coords =c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  st_transform(epsg) %>%
  cbind(st_coordinates(.))

p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = US, aes(x=X, y = Y, group = group), fill="grey", alpha=0.3) +
  geom_point(data = df, alpha = 0.5, aes(x=df$lon, y=df$lat, size=df$manual_prm, color=df$wcng_score)) +
  scale_size_continuous(name="Premium", trans="log",  range=c(0.1,4)) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0.1, 0.9)) +
  scale_color_viridis(name = "Scores", trans="log", option="magma") +
  theme_void() +
  coord_sf(crs = epsg, datum = NA) +
  ggtitle("Scores") +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0.85, 0.8),
    text = element_text(color = "#22211d"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA), 
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA), 
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA),
    plot.title = element_text(size= 16, hjust=0.1, color = "#4e4d47", margin = margin(b = -0.1, t = 0.4, l = 2, unit = "cm"))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this is weird but when I try to run this I keep getting the error could not fund function coord_sf. both packages sf and ggplot2 are loaded.

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned that you need the dev version of ggplot2. Install by doing...devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2"). Note you also need to install 'devtools' package to run 'install_github'

Comment: On closer inspection, looks like `fiftystater` is more suited to choropleth maps. May be possible to get points on it, but probably more work than I anticipated initially.

Comment: fiftystater simply provides the polygon layer within the ggplot. Any number of other layers (points, lines, text, etc) can be added using ggplot. It is exactly the same amount of work as if you had some other source for U.S state polygons

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue now. The problem was that my coordibates for Alaska and Hawaii were in the original position. What I did was to convert my data to a spatial data points and use points_elided from the albersusa package to convert my coordinates to the correct position with the moved Alaska and Hawaii maps.

I added the following code

```
library(albersusa)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(bloom)

# set up reference coordinate system and convert to spatial points
coordinates(df) <- ~lon + lat
latlong = "init=epsg:4326"
proj4string(df) = CRS(latlong)
df <- as.data.frame(points_elided(df))


USA <- usa_composite(proj="laea")  # creates map projection 
USA_MAP <- tidy(USA, region="name")

q <- ggplot() + 
  geom_map(data = USA_MAP, map = USA_MAP, aes(map_id = id), fill=NA, size = 0.1)+
  geom_point(data = df, alpha = 0.5, aes(x=df$lon, y=df$lat, size=df$manual_prm, color=df$wcng_score)) +
  theme_void() +
  coord_map()
```

Comment: I think you need `library(broom)` not `library(bloom)`

Comment: And `latlong = "+init=epsg:4326"`  with the added +